# How to add a Javascript code in my page October CMS

Tags: octobercms

I need to integrate a code given by a supplier into my page and this code is in the form  The code here .

I tried to put it in the text editor in code format, but every time I save it disappears.

Do you know how I can do this? This code displays messages and should only be on this page.

Thank you very much for your help.

Comment: can you please tell us on which page you want to put ?

Comment: I have created a "test" page and in it I have added a column. In the text editor I switched to "Code View" mode and tried to put there my <script> </script>

Comment: code view is only for PHP code

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In OctoberCMS you can add javascript code directly to the page's markup section.

> Please check the below screenshot and add code as shown below

[image: tutorialmeta.com October cms javascript]
ref: [Add Javascript To October Cms Page](https://tutorialmeta.com/octobercms/add-javascript-october-cms-page)

for the more advanced use cases, you can use `scripts placeholder`
ref: https://docs.octobercms.com/2.x/markup/tag-scripts.html

if any doubt please comment.

Comment: I finally did a "partial", added my code in there and was able to add my "Partial" block on the relevant pages. Works perfectly, thanks.

Comment: cool, for more advanced use you can use : https://docs.octobercms.com/2.x/markup/tag-scripts.html